# UCMA 4.0 not working

Tags: ucma

I am  going through the quick start sample provied by UCMA 4.0 SDK.  We have lyncserver 2013and visual studio 2012 installed in the same machine.  We are trying manual provisioning option to log IM messages,  using "RegisterForIncomingCall" event to  listen the traffic.  The application starting successfully, but the event is not getting fired.   We are using the quick start "ManualProvisioning" project, except that configuration. We did disable the firewall and also tried trace through OCS logger. So far no luck. Is there anything else we can try to debug this issue?

Any reply is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Some ideas from my experience: 1. Make sure you are sending and receiving IMs within your server. 2. You can try to use the Lync Logging Tool: http://ucblog.deutinger.de/?p=294. 3. Maybe the sample doesn't work the quite the way you'd expect it to, check any documentation the solution file or folder comes with. 4. Check windows event logger, see if anything shows up there.

Comment: hi guys, can you do me a favor? I want to create a UCMA application and have gotten the server FQDN of our organization. But many problems occur. Please move to and take a scan here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24256539/how-to-connect-to-lync-server-and-how-to-make-port-5061-for-sip-work